# Possible cuts to remove cycles in a directed graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I'm working on a graph related problem. In my application, I'll firstly construct a directed graph by solving an optimization problem. Then, I detect if the directed graph contains any directed cycle via  [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm). Finally, I want to remove directed cycles from the graph by imposing valid constraint and solve the problem again in an iterative fashion.

My question is as follows: Given a directed graph which can contain directed cycles, what possible valid inequalities (i.e., constraints) we can impose to remove one or more directed cycles. There could be many possible inequalities, in fact.

One example that came to my mind is as follows: First detect a directed cycle in a graph. Then construct a directed path from the cycle and impose this constraint: $\sum_{(p,q) \in path} Z_{pq} \leq |path|-1$ where $Z_{ij}=1$ if there is an arc from node i to node j, and 0, otherwise.

Any other suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: it would help to understand how you are representing the graph in your optimization problem, what are the variables, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Z_{jk} indicates if we have an arc from node j to node k. In the objective function, I am minimizing a score function which is linear.